# FooterTemplate cant call any function in my .aspx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, grid

I dont know if I am doing something wrong but what I want to do, is display the number of registries we are retrieving from our database and display it on our footer where we have the "Total applicants: (here we should be able to look at the total number of items)" but I cant even call a asp:label to load it in .aspx.cs. Here is my code: (label should be lblTotal)

```
<blockquote>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvApplicants" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="true"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" CellPadding="5" ForeColor="#333333" 
            GridLines="None" PageSize="10" ShowFooter="True" Width="100%"  Font-Size="9pt"
            OnSorting="gvApplicants_Sorting" OnPageIndexChanging="gvApplicants_PageIndexChanging">

            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="Id" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Complete Name" SortExpression="FirstName">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a href='candidato.aspx?key=<%#Eval("Key")%>'>
                         <%# Eval("FirstName") %>
                         <%# Eval("MiddleName") %>
                         <%# Eval("LastName") %>
                         <%# Eval("SecondLastName") %></a>
                        <br />
                        <small><%# GetLabels(Eval("Id").ToString())%></small>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        Total candidates: <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vacancies" SortExpression="">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# GetVacante(Eval("email").ToString())%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Status.Nombre" HeaderText="Status" 
                    SortExpression="Status.Nombre" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"  ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Created Date" SortExpression="CreatedDate">
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#  Eval("createdDate", "{0:MMMM dd, yyyy. H:mm}") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Rating" HeaderText="Rating" SortExpression="Rating" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"  />
            </Columns>
```

and on .aspx.cs

```
private void LoadApplicants(Entity.Vacante v)
{
    try
    {
        ASF.HC.JobApplication.BO.User u = new BO.User();
        gvApplicants.DataSource = u.GetAllByVacancy(v);
        gvApplicants.DataBind();
        LoadData()

    }

    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        this.lblError.Text = "There was an unexpected error getting applicants: " + ex.Message;
    }
}
    protected void LoadTotal()
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvApplicants.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
            {
                Label myLabel = row.FindControl("lblTotal") as Label;
                if (myLabel != null)
                {
                    myLabel.Text = "hola";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "guys".... you do know that there are female developers?

Comment: I meant guys as in female and male. Guys and gals doesnt seem practical to me.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something wrong. You are still using webforms.
Just joking, the problem is that you can't access controls from template fileds with the id like the other controls. you need to do something like this.

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in myGridView.Rows) {
    if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer) {
        Label myLabel= row.FindControl("myLabelId") as Label;
        if(myLabel!=null)
        {
         //Do your stuff
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not my coding :(, it is for an assignment. Getting back to the programming topic. I can't even show a "Hello World" with this. Am I doing something wrong? I am even loading it again in the Page_Load().

Comment: I added in the original post, what I am trying to simulate